# Gwt iterate on text controls in a Composite

Tags: gwt, gwt2

Can one iterate over all the textbox controls defined in a composite widget?
As in I need to extract values of all textboxes to check if they exist - the textboxes should have some data in them.

So I was hoping to have a method like:

```
for(Widget w: this.getChildren)
 {
      //if widget is a textbox - check value
 }
```

Composite class does not have a method like getChildren neither a method where I can get elements of a given class - or name and if I get all the elements using NodeList then I need to recursively go until I find a textbox. Is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the author of the Composite subclass, you can enable this kind of behavior by implementing HasWidgets (or, more specifically, something like getWidgetIterator()).

There's no way to do this for an arbitrary Composite.

Comment: If one uses HasWidgets - then it would make sense to add widgets to the Composite dynamically and setting provided=true in the UiFields?.Otherewise how would the custom iterator know about number of widgets added if the definitions are there in ui.xml files?

Comment: You would have to program the iterator to know about the widgets.  `ComplexPanel` already implements `HasWidgets`, so if you're creating your ui.xml files with a list of widgets in a FlowPanel (or other complexPanel) you can do something like for (Widget child : flowPanel) {};